# Asyncio RuntimeError: Event Loop is Closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to make a bunch of requests (~1000) using Asyncio and the aiohttp library, but I am running into a problem that I can't find much info on.

When I run this code with 10 urls, it runs just fine. When I run it with 100+ urls, it breaks and gives me `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed` error.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


@asyncio.coroutine
def get_status(url):
    code = '000'
    try:
        res = yield from asyncio.wait_for(aiohttp.request('GET', url), 4)
        code = res.status
        res.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print(code)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ['https://google.com/'] * 100
    coros = [asyncio.Task(get_status(url)) for url in urls]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(coros))
    loop.close()
```

The stack trace can be found [here](https://bpaste.net/show/3ee9e9640987).

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated as I've been banging my head over this for  a few hours now. Obviously this would suggest that an event loop has been closed that should still be open, but I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: is not `Asyncio` error. Python recursive error, reached limit. need thread for all non class function...

Comment: First, make sure you are using the latest aiohttp release.
I assume you do.
Technically aiohttp need one loop iteration after finishing request for closing underlying sockets. 
So insert `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(0))` before `loop.close()` call.

Comment: Your traceback suggests that a job submitted to an [Executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor) through [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor) returned after the loop has been closed. Weirdly enough, [aiohttp](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=run_in_executor&type=Code) and [asyncio](https://github.com/python/asyncio/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=run_in_executor) don't use `run_in_executor`...

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov, thanks for the reply - I tried sleeping before close, but still no dice... any other ideas?

Comment: @Vincent technically they does, DNS resolving is performed by `run_in_executor` -- but it should be done before finishing `get_status` tasks.

Comment: For anyone using python's async socket.io, make sure to run `await sio.wait()` in your main function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, [loop.getaddrinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.getaddrinfo) uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to run `socket.getaddrinfo` in a thread.

You're using [asyncio.wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=wait_for#asyncio.wait_for) with a timeout, which means `res = yield from asyncio.wait_for...` will raise a `asyncio.TimeoutError` after 4 seconds. Then the `get_status` coroutines return `None` and the loop stops. If a job finishes after that, it will try to schedule a callback in the event loop and raises an exception since it is already closed.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, but this is the only way I have found to implement request timeouts. Do you know of a way that I could timeout without closing the loop?

Comment: @PatrickAllen You might want to increase the [number of workers](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/27f3499f968e8734fef91677eb339b5d32a6f675/asyncio/base_events.py#L44) that is 5 by default.

Comment: @PatrickAllen Or use `loop._default_executor.shutdown(wait=True)` before closing the loop.

Comment: I'll mark this as answered, because this seems to have fixed the original problem. Should I be limiting the max number of connections? It seems that requests are timing out for no apparent reason. Maybe I'm making too many requests too quickly?

Comment: @PatrickAllen Well, 5 worker threads and a thousand of request means you're trying to run 200 `socket.getaddrinfo` in 4 seconds which seems reasonable to me, even though the number of workers can be increased. You can also give a custom `TcpConnector` to `request` in order to specify a connection timeout: `connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(loop=loop, force_close=True, conn_timeout=1)`

Answer (score 18):

The bug is filed as https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/258 
Stay tuned.

As quick workaround I suggest using custom executor, e.g.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
loop.set_default_executor(executor)
```

Before finishing your program please do

```
executor.shutdown(wait=True)
loop.close()
```

Comment: Awesome Andrew, thanks for your help. I didn't realize I was talking to part of the team :). Following this on GH

Comment: `Changed in version 3.5.3: BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor() no longer configures the max_workers of the thread pool executor it creates`

Comment: Andrew, can you suggest not "quick workaround" but some robust workaround for Python 3.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the interpreter. Fortunately, it was finally fixed in 3.10.6 so you just need to update your installed Python.