# Aiohttp, Asyncio: RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have two scripts, scraper.py and db_control.py. In scraper.py I have something like this:

```
...
def scrape(category, field, pages, search, use_proxy, proxy_file):
    ...
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    to_do = [ get_pages(url, params, conngen) for url in urls ]
    wait_coro = asyncio.wait(to_do)
    res, _ = loop.run_until_complete(wait_coro)
    ...
    loop.close()
    
    return [ x.result() for x in res ]

...
```

And in db_control.py:

```
from scraper import scrape
...
while new < 15:
    data = scrape(category, field, pages, search, use_proxy, proxy_file)
    ...
...
```

Theoretically, scraper should be started unknown-times until enough of data have been obtained. But when `new` is not imidiatelly `> 15` then this error occurs:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 293, in run_until_complete
self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 265, in _check_closed
raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

But scripts works just fine if I run scrape() only once. So I guess there is some problem with recreating `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`, I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598231/asyncio-runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed) but nothing changed. How I can fix this? Of course those are just snippets of my code, if you think problem can be elsewhere, full code is available [here](https://github.com/kongzii/korpi/tree/master/korpi/lib).

Comment: fyi it's __scraper__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrapper

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Methods [`run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_until_complete), [`run_forever`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_forever), [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor), [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.create_task), [`call_at`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.call_at) explicitly check
the loop and throw exception if it's closed.

Quote from docs - [`BaseEvenLoop.close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.close):

> This is idempotent and **irreversible**

---

Unless you have some(good) reasons, you might simply omit the close line:

```
def scrape(category, field, pages, search, use_proxy, proxy_file):
    #...
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    to_do = [ get_pages(url, params, conngen) for url in urls ]
    wait_coro = asyncio.wait(to_do)
    res, _ = loop.run_until_complete(wait_coro)
    #...
    # loop.close()
    return [ x.result() for x in res ]
```

If you want to have each time a brand new loop, you have t create it manually and set as default:

```
def scrape(category, field, pages, search, use_proxy, proxy_file):
    #...
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)    
    to_do = [ get_pages(url, params, conngen) for url in urls ]
    wait_coro = asyncio.wait(to_do)
    res, _ = loop.run_until_complete(wait_coro)
    #...
    return [ x.result() for x in res ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm now :)

Comment: Should the `loop` in the first code snippet be closed? If so, where?