# How to treat and deal with event loops?

Tags: cpython

Is a `loop.close()` needed prior to returning async values in the below code?

```
import asyncio

async def request_url(url):
    return url

def fetch_urls(x):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[request_url(url) for url in x]))
```

That is, should `fetch_urls` be like this instead?:

```
def fetch_urls(x):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*[request_url(url) for url in x]))
    loop.close()
    return results
```

If the `loop.close()` is needed, then how can `fetch_urls` be called again without raising the exception: `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`?

A [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598231/asyncio-runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed) states that it is good practice to close the loops and start new ones however it does not specify how new loops can be opened?

Comment: For completeness's sake, you can start a new event loop by call `asyncio.new_event_loop()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the async function (`request` in this case) should not be closing the event loop.  The command `loop.run_until_complete` will <strike>close</strike> stop the event loop as soon as it runs out of things to do.

`fetch_urls` should be the second version -- that is, it will get an event loop, run the event loop until there is nothing left to do, and then closes it `loop.close()`.

Comment: run_until_complete() **`stop()`s** the loop, it doesn't **close** it.

Comment: @Udi:  Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Dave:  Check the updates, please; I was wrong before.

Answer (score 2):

You can also keep the event loop alive, and close it the end of your program, using `run_until_complete` more than once:

```
import asyncio


async def request_url(url):
    return url


def fetch_urls(loop, urls):
    tasks = [request_url(url) for url in urls]
    return loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks, loop=loop))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    print(fetch_urls(loop, ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']))
    print(fetch_urls(loop, ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']))
    print(fetch_urls(loop, ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']))
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great example :)