# asyncio: unable to create new event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, autobahn

I am using Python 3.6.2, on Fedora 26 Workstation.

Below is some scrapbook code which demonstrates my issue:

EDIT: added Sam Hartman's suggestion to code.

```
import asyncio, json
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol, WebSocketClientFactory

class MyClientProtocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, response):
        print(response.peer)

    def onOpen(self):
        print("open")
        self.sendMessage(json.dumps({'command': 'subscribe', 'channel': "1010"}).encode("utf8"))

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        print("message")
        print(json.loads(payload))

factory1 = WebSocketClientFactory("wss://api2.poloniex.com:443")
factory1.protocol = MyClientProtocol
loop1 = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop1.run_until_complete(loop1.create_connection(factory1, "api2.poloniex.com", 443, ssl=True))

try:
    loop1.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
loop1.close()

asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())

factory2 = WebSocketClientFactory("wss://api2.poloniex.com:443")
factory2.protocol = MyClientProtocol
loop2 = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop2.run_until_complete(loop2.create_connection(factory2, "api2.poloniex.com", 443, ssl=True))

try:
    loop2.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
loop2.close()
```

After having closed an initial asyncio event loop, creating another and setting it as the global event loop, attempting to use the new event loop yields the following errors:

```
Fatal write error on socket transport
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7f8a84ed4748>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=6>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 762, in write
    n = self._sock.send(data)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Fatal error on SSL transport
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7f8a84ed4748>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport closing fd=6>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 762, in write
    n = self._sock.send(data)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 648, in _process_write_backlog
    self._transport.write(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 766, in write
    self._fatal_error(exc, 'Fatal write error on socket transport')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 646, in _fatal_error
    self._force_close(exc)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 658, in _force_close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, exc)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 574, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 357, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception in callback _SelectorSocketTransport._read_ready()
handle: <Handle _SelectorSocketTransport._read_ready()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/txaio/_common.py", line 63, in call_later
    self._buckets[real_time][1].append(call)
KeyError: 412835000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 127, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 731, in _read_ready
    self._protocol.data_received(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 503, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 204, in feed_ssldata
    self._handshake_cb(None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 619, in _on_handshake_complete
    self._app_protocol.connection_made(self._app_transport)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autobahn/asyncio/websocket.py", line 97, in connection_made
    self._connectionMade()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py", line 3340, in _connectionMade
    WebSocketProtocol._connectionMade(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py", line 1055, in _connectionMade
    self.onOpenHandshakeTimeout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/txaio/_common.py", line 72, in call_later
    self._notify_bucket, real_time,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/txaio/aio.py", line 382, in call_later
    return self._config.loop.call_later(delay, real_call)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 543, in call_later
    timer = self.call_at(self.time() + delay, callback, *args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 553, in call_at
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 357, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

It seems reasonable that one might need to reopen an event loop after having closed an earlier one. Indeed this question even shows how: [Asyncio Event Loop is Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600579/asyncio-event-loop-is-closed)

The code below should achieve this:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

so I am clearly doing something wrong. Can somebody see something missing?

Comment: Have you tried running `loop.stop()` instead of `close()`?

Comment: The event loop is not running at the point where I call `loop.close()`, so it would be a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

I have fairly high confidence that your factory object is maintaining a reference to the old event loop presumably that it gets from `asyncio.get_event_loop`.  Asyncio consumers are bad about getting hidden references to loops.

My recommendation is to  reconstruct the web socket factory after closing the loop

Comment: Thanks Sam. I tried reconstructing the factory, even using different variable names for the first and second factory/loop, but I am still getting the same errors (`OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`, `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`, `KeyError: 15068000`). It's as if the `set_event_loop` call is simply not working. Do you think I should report this as a bug?

Comment: You can check that set_event_loop is working with an assert after that get_event_loop returns what you set it to.  It's almost certainly dangling references somewhere, probably in your websocket implementation

Comment: OK. I'll ask the autobahn.asyncio folks. Thanks Sam.

Comment: Upstream bug report, for those who are interested: https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/issues/925