# Asyncio ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Running on Windows, this code has worked for a while, but crashes with a `ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()` if workload is too high.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

class Multiple_HTTP:
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    async def fetch(session,url):
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                status  =   response.status
                text    =   await response.text()
                return (url,status,text)
        except Exception as e:
            return e
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    async def fetch_all(urls,timeout):
        loop            =   asyncio.get_event_loop()
        session_timeout =   aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=None,sock_connect=timeout,sock_read=timeout)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop , timeout=session_timeout , connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)) as session:
            cwlist  =   [loop.create_task(Multiple_HTTP.fetch(session,url)) for url in urls]
            results =   []
            results =   await asyncio.gather(*cwlist,return_exceptions=True)
            return results
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    def run(urls,timeout=5):
        return asyncio.run(Multiple_HTTP.fetch_all(urls,timeout))
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Based on this other question ([Python asyncio/aiohttp: ValueError: too many file descriptors in select() on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675410/python-asyncio-aiohttp-valueerror-too-many-file-descriptors-in-select-on-win)), I modified to use a ProactorEventLoop and an asyncio.Semaphore, such as:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import sys

class Multiple_HTTP:
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    async def fetch(session,url,semaphore):
        try:
            async with semaphore , session.get(url) as response:
                status  =   response.status
                text    =   await response.text()
                return (url,status,text)
        except Exception as e:
            return e
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    async def fetch_all(urls,timeout,N):
        semaphore       =   asyncio.Semaphore(N)
        loop            =   None
        tcp_limit       =   N
        if(sys.platform=='win32'):
            tcp_limit   =   60
            loop        =   asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop            =   asyncio.get_event_loop()
        session_timeout =   aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=None,sock_connect=timeout,sock_read=timeout)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop , timeout=session_timeout , connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False,limit=tcp_limit)) as session:
            cwlist  =   [loop.create_task(Multiple_HTTP.fetch(session,url,semaphore)) for url in urls]
            results =   []
            results =   await asyncio.gather(*cwlist,return_exceptions=True)
            return results
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    def run(urls,timeout=5,N=60):
        return asyncio.run(Multiple_HTTP.fetch_all(urls,timeout,N))
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But now the `ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()` is happening when running for a couple of minutes, instead of 3 hours as in previous version.

How should I correct my code to contain concurrency so that ValueError is not raised?

Comment: Are you calling multiple instances of Multiple_HTTP? I ran your code with the Windows specials removed, with 1million requests and N=1000 and couldn't get it to fail with Python 3.10.7 and aiohttp 3.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

After some extensive debugging, this is what it is happening:

The code hangs at the .get in  `async with session.get(url) as response:`, which leaves plenty of file descriptors open.

Not to mess this question up, I'll post a new one with the issue I just described.