# Running a parallelised recursive python program on GPU while still maintaining functionality of global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallelism-amdahl

My problem essentially boils down to "How do I get this bit of threaded Python code to run on my GPU instead of my CPU?"

I'm working on a program that's similar to a Travelling Salesman problem where I recursively check each possible move (with optimisations of course). The tricky thing is the retention of global variables - python's native threading does this very well, and the algorithm I'm using relies entirely on global variables - gross, I know. At the risk of going into too much detail, many of my threads will have to spawn separate threads of their own, up until a certain 'depth' (I've found around 3 works best), at which point each thread will no longer be parallelised, and the function will be executed linearly instead.

It worked decently well at first, and then I had some performance improvements from threading it. However, it's still not good enough - if I can maintain global variables, then in theory this program can be completely parallelised, and hence I think it would be able to run very quickly on a GPU.

The code's messy at the moment, but here's the general idea expressed in pseudocode:

```
int x

function f( depth ):         # THE RECURSIVE f( n ) TEMPLATE

   global x
   # do stuff with x

   if depth <= maxDepth then # if we're still below the max depth
                             #    then we'll thread the next round of recursion.

      for i = 0 to n         # this number will change each time

         call_in_thread( target = f,
                         args   = depth + 1
                         )   # obviously the arguments
                             # passed to each thread will be a little different,
                             # but that shouldn't be a problem

   else                      # if we're already past the max depth,
                             # then we won't bother parallelising,
                             #      as the overheads would outweigh the benefits

      for i = 0 to n         # 

         f( depth + 1 )      # THE SELF-RECURSIVE CALL
```

So my question is simple - can I (easily) translate from a threaded python program to a threaded python program that runs on my GPU while still maintaining use of global variables? I'm aware of the existence of Numba/NumbaPro, but they're very intimidating packages, and I'm not sure how well a program like mine would translate into that framework.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "no".  GPUs are not at all like CPUs, and generally speaking you can't take a CPU-style program and run it on a GPU; you'd need to redesign the program from scratch to take advantage of the GPU's architecture.  Your best bet (if you don't want to spend a lot of time learning GPU programming) would be to find a library that already does what you want on a GPU, and use it.

Answer (score -1):

> ### Q: *can I <sub>(easily)</sub> translate from a threaded python program to a threaded python program that runs on my GPU while still maintaining use of global variables?*

A: Principally neither at all, the less easily :

### Here is the WHY part :

**a)** the recursion, formally sketched in the pseudo-**code** above, is **flawed**. It does not control its own termination, but rather diverges into infinity, accumulating all the per-pass allocated resources stay and wait for the recursion deepest point-of-a-return, only since which it starts to release any of the such waiting resources allocations, as the recursion consolidation phase "bubbles" back to the initial caller.

**b)** python **Threads** ( as of 2019-Q3 ) are principally zero-concurrent, [due to the **GIL**-lock **prevented** concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57137154) and python threading-concurrent processing knowingly operate worse ( due to new overheads added ) then a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** process-flow ( with an exception: where latency-masking ( hiding external or I/O related request/response delays and transport latencies ) may benefit from multi-threaded slow tasks separation into multiple threads, where the concurrency of waiting-times is the source of improvements, if compared to a pure-`[SERIAL]` ordering of both the request, the waiting time and the postprocessing of the response, after it has finally arrived (or not) )

**c)** a generic **recursion** is a form of a pure-`[SERIAL]` many levels deep ( sometimes very deep, yet never infinite ) nesting, with a deferred use of a deeper-level to be yet calculated value, during a "back-propagation" of a terminal value, all the way back, through a consolidation phase of the recursion. While specific chances are, a generic algorithm, that uses a form of recursion for self-expression, could hardly get parallelised, the less [**efficiently parallelised** ( see the role of all add-on costs in the Amdahl's Law )](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3), w.r.t. the add-on overhead costs for doing that. Plus a "density" of computing goes during the recursive calls way down, while resources needs grow all that way up. The rules of the Computer Science are quite clear in this. Watch and [**play with this fully interactive animated impact**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vycmsfuywj) analysis and try to move the **`p`**-slider, for the `[PARALLEL]`-fraction of the processing, anywhere lower than the un-realistic 100% parallel-code as if having zero-instatiation add-on costs, as if having zero-transfer add-on costs, as if having zero-results-consolidation add-on costs, so as to at least "smell the smoke" of the real-life fire.

**d)** NUMA-ecosystems ( **N**on-**U**niform **M**emory **A**ccess systems, the more the one provided via a proxy-(device-driver)-mediated access to a foreign language ( be it a CUDA c-language, an OpenCL, an SoC/FPGA-based hybrid one or any other, compiled into a static-GPU-kernel code, transferred into the "inside" of the GPU-card and "let" rather autonomously execute there ) hosted on a remote, distributed hardware, as GPU-s are an example of ) are hard to expect to have all the properties, native in the call-initiating sub-system, evenly available and working, the less a both-way coordinated propagation of changes in state/value. Using **`global`** variables on the python side is also strongly discouraged ( except known cases ) even inside a homogeneous python-only software

**e)** python **scripts** ( the programs that the python interpreter interpretes ), the less the threaded-ones, do not run on GPU. GPU-devices have also their units of code-execution called threads, but these are being executed on a principally different hardware (vendor-specific SM-based devices), that exhibit SIMD-parallelism, so autonomously operated threads, where each one has a different code to execute or even having the same code but a different ( divergent in GPU-jargon ) code-execution path, the SIMD-device will waste time in scheduling SIMD-executable threads and letting all the incoherent SIMD-threads waiting their (divergent) turn, till their instruction (different per-thread) will get all-SIMD "free" to execute, if no other SIMD-thread in the block has the very same SIMD-instruction to execute. One can guess the immense performance deterioration if divergent threads have to wait on ~ < 2 GHz SIMD-device to some future time, where the 32-threads-(warp)-wide SIMD-device gets all free from any other work and can first "privately" serve a one (divergent)-SIMD-thread. Yes, there are python-tools, that enable python program to prepare another, "embedded", block-of-code, that will then get transformed, then get compiled, then downloaded via the GPU-device queues to the fabric and scheduled for the remote execution on the GPU-device, yet these all transformations are complex, so as to make the high-level idea of how such a class of algorithms get transformed onto a foreign device computing device, using a foreign device processor's machine-code for execution there, while also having to obey all the known foreign-device-specific constraints on resources and processing-organisation policies.

**f)** GPU hosted kernel-code is indeed extremely sensitive to **resources** use, the more if recursive. The depth-of-recursion for any kind of recursive algorithms ( the one here is diverging, as noted in item a) ) may on its own even cause a correctly formulated recursive code straight impossible to be run inside a GPU-device, right due to the fixed and rather low amounts of high-performance on-chip memory resources ( size of the SM cache is very limited even on HPC-motivated GPU-fabrics if compared to sizes thereof on contemporary CPU-s, not speaking about the mainstream, primarily gaming-oriented, GPU-cards ).