# Multi Thread Requests Python3

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, python-multithreading

I have researched a lot on this topic but the problem is am not able to figure out how to send multi-threading post requests using python3

```
names = ["dfg","dddfg","qwed"]

for name in names :
    res = requests.post(url,data=name)
    res.text
```

Here I want to send all these names and I want to use multi threading to make it faster.

Comment: It's better if you use asyncio and aiohttp for python 3

Comment: +1 @bigbounty. I can't stress this enough. OP, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924319/1305461) out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Solution 1 - [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) fixed number of threads

Using a custom function (`request_post`) you can do almost anything.

```
import concurrent
import requests

def request_post(url, data):
    return requests.post(url, data=data)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor: # optimally defined number of threads
    res = [executor.submit(request_post, url, data) for data in names]
    concurrent.futures.wait(res)
```

`res` will be list of [`request.Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response) for each request made wrapped on `Future` instances. To access the `request.Response` you need to use `res[index].result()` where `index` size is `len(names)`.

Future objects give you better control on the responses received, like if it completed correctly or there was an exception or time-out etc.  More about [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.wait)

*You don't take risk of problems related to [high number of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18647230/1207193) (solution 2).*

---

#### Solution 2 - [`multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) and spawn one thread for each request

Might be usefull if you are not requesting a lot of pages and also or if the response time is quite slow.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import itertools
import requests

with ThreadPool(len(names)) as pool: # creates a Pool of 3 threads 
    res = pool.starmap(requests.post(itertools.repeat(url),names))
```

`pool.starmap` - is used to pass (*map*) multiple arguments to one function (`requests.post`) that is gonna be called by a list of Threads (`ThreadPool`). It will return a list of [`request.Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response) for each request made.

`itertools.repeat(url)` is needed to make the first argument be repeated the same number of threads being created.

`names` is the second argument of `requests.post` so it's gonna work without needing to explicitly use the optional parameter `data`. Its len must be the same of the number of threads being created.

*This code will not work if you needed to call another parameter like an optional one*

Comment: Actually can you add comments not so known to python right now so that i can understand this code a little bit more that what actually what part is doing

Comment: Maybe this second one will work but no idea that how i can implement it here

Comment: while i < len(name):
  print(i,idx)
  try:
   loadproxy = {
    "https":"https://"+proxys[idx],
   }
   myobj= {"name":name[i],"stats":playerStats[i]}
   res = requests.post(url, json = myobj,proxies=loadproxy,timeout=100)
   i+=1
   idx+=1
   if(SuccessKey):
    if(SuccessKey in res.text):
     print(res.text)
    else:
     print("Can't add Failed")
   elif(FailureKey):
    if(FailureKey not in res.text):
     print(res.text)
    else:
     print("Can't add Failed")
  except Exception as e:
   print("Something Went Wrong")
   idx+=1
   continue

Comment: If You can guide it will be helpfull

Comment: can you post this detailed requeriments on the body of the question? I am quite not getting your problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214611/discussion-between-eusoubrasileiro-and-for-this).

Comment: Note that with concurrent futures both ThreadPool (which you want to use for IO bound tasks like this) and ProcessPool both have defaults for number of workers that usually work pretty optimally.
So in the above concurrent.futures example you can leave the worker count empty and make the best use of resources: with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: thanks @Richard you are right. I will comment that on the answer.