# How to start a pool of threads and stop when one is finished in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am trying to write a function that sends multiple requests at once, and returns the first response. I am currently using a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` object. I understand that stopping a request in the middle is complicated, so instead I thought I could keep the other threads in the background and return a value early. However, the function seems to wait for the other threads to finish before returning. How can I prevent that? My code looks like this:

```
def req(urls):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for url in urls:
            futures.append(executor.submit(get_request, url))
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            if future.result():
                return future.result()  # Other threads should stop now
    return False  # No valid response was sent
```

Comment: Multithreading for I/O operations is not the way to go in Python due to the [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). Look into asynchronous I/O via `asyncio`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126286/fastest-parallel-requests-in-python/57129241#57129241).

Answer (score 2):

Try shutdown https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown

```py
def req(urls):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        for url in urls:
            futures.append(executor.submit(get_request, url))
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            if future.result():
                executor.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)
                return future.result()  # Other threads should stop now
    return False  # No valid response was sent
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems my python is outdated and I can't use the `cancel_futures` option.

Comment: you can also loop through all futures and call `.cancel()` on each of them

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.cancel

Comment: `cancel` returns False, because the thread is still pending.