# How can I send 100 requests at once

Tags: multithreading, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

```
 import requests as r
 for key in open('exmp.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines():
     try:
         data = { 'secret_id': key }
         first = r.post('https://myurl.com', data = data)
         print(f"{key} | {first.json()['message']}")
     except:
         pass
```

> It's just a simple code that gives response one by one which takes forever to complete I want to send 100 requests at once but I have no idea what should I use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest parallel requests in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126286/fastest-parallel-requests-in-python)