# Is there a faster/more efficient way than a loop to make multiple api requests from a list?

Tags: python, api, loops

I have a list of about 70 items and I need to make an api request for each item. I am currently using a for loop to go through each item in that list and make the api request. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I would imagine there is a way to make the api requests simultaneously instead of looping.

Comment: You need some sort of loop. You might use threads to make the requests concurrently instead of serially, but depending on how long each request takes, the overhead may not be worth it.

Comment: You could write the code using python's async services (that would include the api request itself) or use a `mulitprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

Comment: @chepner You can make many more async requests than you can with threading

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest parallel requests in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126286/fastest-parallel-requests-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of parallelism if possible, such as the `Pool` class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `httpx`

```
async def send_request(item):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
       r = await client.get('https://www.example.com/', data=item)
    return r.json()

async def main():
    data = [{"hi": 1}, {"hi": 2}]
    coros = [send_request(x) for x in data]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*coros)
    return results


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use standard python library `threading`:

```
def name_func(param):
    do something

thread1=threading.Thread(target=name_func, args =(a,))
thread2=threading.Thread(target=name_func, args =(b,))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```