# asyncio.run RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-asyncio, roblox, event-loop

```py
import robloxapi, asyncio
client = robloxapi.Client(".ROBLOSECURITY Cookie Here") # Removed this for security reasons

async def main():
    user = await client.get_self()

    try:
        role = await user.get_role_in_group(1)
    except robloxapi.utils.errors.NotFound:
        role = None

    if role:    
        print(role.name)
    else:
        print("Not in group")

asyncio.run(main())
```

This code is raising `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed` and I don't have a clue why,

I have tried replacing asyncio.run with this

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

but it gave me the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600579/asyncio-event-loop-is-closed . I haven't flagged

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to change anything I'm still having the same error, also, In the comments they mentioned that it has that behavior by default when you use asyncio.run

Comment: I ended up running it in WSL and the exact same code worked

Comment: @Filip, i am  making a writing a general answer about proactor en selector event loops to help some people out here. I was wondering if my answer helped you out? Could you give some feedback?

Answer (score 18):

On Windows do this:

```py
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks! I was getting angry because I wrote a correct code but constantly received this annoying error. So simple solution :).

Comment: This worked for me. For those of you wondering [why](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-policy.html?highlight=asyncio%20set_event_loop_policy#asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy).

Answer (score 3):

I am new to StackOverflow and i can not write comments. So i will write it here as an answer. I ran into a similar problem with asyncio.

So the issue i had was solved by changing the Eventloop python was using.

In python versions lower than 3.8-:

- SelectorEventLoop is used on windows
- ProactorEventLoop is used on Linux.

(in python 3.8+ they are both ProactorEventLoop) So this will not help u out if u have python 3.8+ installed. As u will have the same eventloop on windows as on WSL.

if you do have a python version lower than 3.8- This will probably help you.

So you can try to manualy set the ProactorEventLoop wich is also used when u are using WSL

```
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.ProactorEventLoop())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

I hope this information will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out how to do this recently because I was having HELLA trouble with this problem. I found this answer on here and none of these worked for me. This post about the [RuntimeError: Event loop closed error](https://pythonalgos.com/runtimeerror-event-loop-is-closed-asyncio-fix/) from PythonAlgos explains it really well. Here's the code if you just want to copy and paste:

```
from functools import wraps


from asyncio.proactor_events import _ProactorBasePipeTransport
 
def silence_event_loop_closed(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except RuntimeError as e:
            if str(e) != 'Event loop is closed':
                raise
    return wrapper
 
_ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ = silence_event_loop_closed(_ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__)
```