# "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed" in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot with discord.py, it loads a token from a file then checks if its real and when im trying to check if it is real or not it is giving this error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001D73EAB1B80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

my code:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import colorama
from colorama import init, Fore
import discord

init()

client = discord.Client()

logo = """
\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗ \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗
\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗ \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║╚\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗ \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╔╝\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╔════╝╚══\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╔══╝\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╔════╝
\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╔\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╔\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║ ╚\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╔╝ \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║     
\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║╚\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╔╝\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║  ╚\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╔╝  ╚════\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║     
\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║ ╚═╝ \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║   \u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m║╚\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m\u001b[37m█\u001b[35m╗
╚═╝     ╚═╝   ╚═╝   ╚══════╝   ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═════╝
""" + Fore.RESET

errortext = "[" + Fore.RED + "ERROR" + Fore.RESET + "] "
infotext = "[" + Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "INFO" + Fore.RESET + "] "
print(logo)
try:
  token = open("token.txt", "r").read()
except:
  print(errortext + "NO \"TOKEN\" FILE FOUND")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(infotext + 'SUCCESFULLY LOGGED IN AS {0.user}'.format(client))

try:
    client.run(token)
except:
    print("")
```

If anyone know why this is happening please tell me :)

Comment: Can you post the **whole** traceback? Not just a part of it.

Comment: that is the whole traceback

Comment: I doubt that, you're not using anywhere `loop.close()`, it must be a derived error from another error

Comment: it definitely is

Comment: Then I doubt you're gonna get an answer at all, the error is very vague, but maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600579/asyncio-event-loop-is-closed-when-getting-loop

Comment: Try taking the client.run() call outside of the try...except block. Maybe then you'll get the full traceback.